# jqgrid sopt not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a strange problem with my sopt search options in my jqgrid. I have specified the sopt fields I want but strangely it displays all the options on some fields and for some it displays the ones I've specified.
Here is my code

```
grid3 = $('#BillInformation').jqGrid({
            url: 'CaseInfo/DisplayBillInfoGrid/' + '?caseID=' + caseID,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'post',
            colNames: ['CaseID', 'Case Status', 'Billing Type', 'Date of Service', 'CPT Code', 'Units', 'Invoice #', 'PackageID',
            'Billing Date', 'Payment Date', 'Provider Due', 'Provider Charge', 'Medrisk Charge', 'Amount Billed', 'Less Savings',
            'Amount Collected', 'Adjusted', 'Refunded', 'Provider Charge Date'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'CaseID', index: 'CaseID', width: 70, align: 'left', formatter: genericcursor,
                searchOptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] }
            }, // DISPLAYS ALL THE SOPTS
            { name: 'CaseStatus', index: 'CaseStatus', width: 75, align: 'left',
                searchOptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'nc', 'eq', 'ne'] }
            }, // DISPLAYS ALL THE SOPTS
            ...
            { name: 'Date of Service', index: 'Date_of_Service', width: 100, align: 'left', formatter: dosbutton,
                searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'] } 
            }, // DISPLAYS THE SOPTS I'VE SPECIFIED
            ...
});

grid3.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false },
        {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false });
```

I'm really stumped as to why this is happening and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Urgh. I've solved it. You need to put searchoptions instead of searchOptions. Took me an hour to figure that out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) option, but no `searchOptions` which you use in the `'CaseID'` and `'CaseStatus'`. You should just write the name in correct case.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that after posting the question. I have another question. The filters string that is posted to the controller always has the 'eq' operation even if I select another operation. However, it is correctly getting the field and data though.

Comment: @brasewel: I never have the problem with wrong operation name. Do you have the problem with all columns or with the specific one? I just seen that you have `name: 'Date of Service'` in one column, but the `name` property should not contain any meta-charackters like blanks. You should rename `name: 'Date of Service'` to `name: 'DateOfService'`, ``name: 'Date_of_Service'`` or any other name.

Comment: I had this issue with all the columns. After doing some research, I solved the problem by adding handler: function (event) { jQuery(".ui-searchFilter td.ops select").filter(function () { return $(this).css("display") != "none"; }).attr("name", "op"); } It seems to work perfectly now

Comment: @brasewel: It seems very strange. Probably you should post more detailed description of the problem in the [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/). The best is always the demo which can be used to reproduce the bug and then your workaround.